# Writing to text file issue

Tags: java, text, file-io

```
public static void makeSandwich()
{
    System.out.println("Enter First Name: ");
    String name = Scanner.next();
    double price = sandwich.getBreadPrice() + sandwich.getMeatPrice() + sandwich.getVegPrice();
    sandwich.setPrice(price);
    NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();

    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date) + " " + name + " " + sandwich.getBread() + " " + sandwich.getMeat() + " " + sandwich.getVegetables() + " " + currency.format(sandwich.getPrice()));
    OrderLine.writeOrderLine(name, sandwich.getBread(), sandwich.getMeat(), sandwich.getVegetables(), sandwich.getPrice());
}
```

and heres my code for the orderline.app

```
public class OrderLine{
    private static Sandwich sandwich = null;

    public static void writeOrderLine(String name, String bread, String meat, String veg, double price)
    {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        try
        {
            File productsFile = new File("orderline.txt");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter(productsFile, true)));

           out.print(dateFormat.format(date) + "\t");
           out.print(name + "\t");
           out.print(sandwich.getBread() + "\t");
           out.print(sandwich.getMeat() + "\t");
           out.print(sandwich.getVegetables() + "\t");
           out.println(sandwich.getPrice() + "\t");
           out.close();
       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {
           System.out.println(e);
       }
    }
}
```

It doesn't print at all, but when I add this line "sandwich = new Sandwich()" before the dateformat in the orderline.java it works but it ends up giving me empty strings since i guess i'm creating a new sandwich. How can I call the sandwich I already made?

Comment: Yum, sandwiches.  You should pass your `sandwich` instance from within the `makeSandwich()` method as a parameter to `writeOrderLine()`, rather than the various components of the sandwich.

Comment: could you clarify? i thought I was already sending my sandwich instance as a parameter   OrderLine.writeOrderLine(name, sandwich.getBread(), sandwich.getMeat(), sandwich.getVegetables(), sandwich.getPrice());

Comment: Again, those are the various components of the sandwich, rather than the `sandwich` itself.  The only parameter should be `Sandwich sandwich`.

Comment: Hmm I just tried OrderLine.writeOrderLine(Sandwich sandwich) it gives me cannot find symbol error.

Comment: You only need to pass the variable name to the method call: `OrderLine.writeOrderLine(sandwich)`.  Your method declaration should be `public static void writeOrderLine(Sandwich sandwich)`.  I recommend that you research/learn more about Java syntax.

Comment: where have you instantiated your sandwich? I suppose it should be done at the top of makeSandwich() method. and I cannot find anything like sandwich.setBread("belabela"). plus just pass your sandwich object to writeOrderLine(Sandwich sandwich) method not each property individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the writeOrderLine function you have not initialized sandwich but passing all the attribute of sandwich either you could do it the following way

```
 public static void writeOrderLine(String name, String bread, String meat, String veg, double price)
        {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = new Date();
            try
            {
                File productsFile = new File("orderline.txt");
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                    new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter(productsFile, true)));

               out.print(dateFormat.format(date) + "\t");
               out.print(name + "\t");
               out.print(bread + "\t");
               out.print(meat + "\t");
               out.print(veg + "\t");
               out.println(price+ "\t");
               out.close();
           }
           catch (IOException e)
           {
               System.out.println(e);
           }
        }
```

or you could do it this way

calling like this

```
OrderLine.writeOrderLine(name, sandwich);
```

and changing the function as

```
public static void writeOrderLine(String name, Sandwich sandwich)
    {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        try
        {
            File productsFile = new File("orderline.txt");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter(productsFile, true)));

           out.print(dateFormat.format(date) + "\t");
           out.print(name + "\t");
           out.print(sandwich.getBread() + "\t");
           out.print(sandwich.getMeat() + "\t");
           out.print(sandwich.getVegetables() + "\t");
           out.println(sandwich.getPrice() + "\t");
           out.close();
       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {
           System.out.println(e);
       }
    }
```